# Leibniz integral rule application

Tags: calculus, integration

Where $c >0$, $\rho >0$, $\mathbf{A}$ is a mapping from $\mathbb{R}^n$, $\mathbf{v}$ and $\mathbf{x}$ are vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$, I have the following expression

\begin{equation}
\label{eq1}
\frac{1}{c} \bigg \| \left(\int_0^c \mathbf{A}(\mathbf{x} + t\mathbf{v})\, dt\right)\mathbf{v} \bigg \| \leq \rho\|\mathbf{v}\|.
\end{equation}
Letting $c \rightarrow 0$ and using the Leibniz integral rule we obtain,
\begin{equation}
\label{eq2}
\|\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{x})\mathbf{v}\| \leq \rho\|\mathbf{v}\|.
\end{equation}

I am struggling to understand what happens when we let $c \rightarrow 0$ and use the Leibniz integral rule. Does anyone know the intermediate steps?

Comment: Are there any assumptions on the map ${\bf A}$? At the moment ${\bf A}$ could be discontinuous at the single point ${\bf x}$.

Comment: $\mathbf{A}$ is the Jacobian of $\mathbf{B} \in \mathcal{C}^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ which is lipschitz continuously differentiable on $\mathbb{R}^n$

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the function $x\mapsto A(x)$ is continuous. Let an $x$ and a $v$ be given. We have to prove that your first inequality implies the second.

Let an $\epsilon>0$ be given. There is a $c>0$ such that
$$\|A(x+tv)-A(x)\|\leq\epsilon\qquad(0\leq t\leq c)\ .$$
It follows that
$$|A(x)v|\leq|A(x+tv)v|+\epsilon|v|\qquad(0\leq t\leq c)\ .$$
Your first inequality then allows to conclude that
$$|A(x)v|\leq\rho|v|+\epsilon|v|\ ,$$
and as $\epsilon>0$ was arbitrary it then follows that in fact
$$|A(x)v|\leq\rho|v|\ .$$